# Wrong post revision shown when editing a rolled-back post

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, ios-app, rollbacks

When you edit a post, whose latest "edit" was a rollback, the markup for the rolled-back revision is loaded in the text editor, rather than the *current* revision.

For example (note example will only work as long as no-one updates the subject post):

1. Go to this post: [When calling delete for LinkedList, variable is being assigned different memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26074824)
2. Note how the following text doesn't appear after the second paragraph:

   > ***SOLUTION******* explicitly set currentSet to nullptr: currentSet = nullptr;
   >   ***END SOLUTION***
3. Click "Edit"
4. Notice how the above text is shown in the text editor.

> [image].[image]

From looking at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/26074824/revisions) for the post, it seems to be because the above text was edited in, *then rolled back*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug in our API with selecting the proper revision to return.

The latest deploy fixed it, no app update should be necessary.